# Starting a process using posix_spawn

Tags: c++, linux

i am using the folowing code to launch the new process in Linux

```
pid_t processID;
char *argV[] = {"192.168.1.40",(char *) 0};
int status = -1;
status = posix_spawn(&processID,"/home/user/application",NULL,NULL,argV,environ);
if(status == 0)
     std::cout<<"Launched Application";
else
     std::cout<<"Launching application Failed";
```

Application did launches but says no command line argument. What is the error in posix_spawn arguments?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the `posix_spawn` manual page:

> The argument argv is a pointer to a null-terminated array of character pointers to null-terminated character strings.  These strings construct the argument list to be made available to the new process.  At least argv[0] must be present in the array, and *should contain the file name of the program being spawned*, e.g. the last component of the path or file argument.

What's happening is that in the launched process, `argv[0]` will be `192.168.1.40` instead of the name of the executable, and there are no arguments to the program after that.

so change:

```
 char *argV[] = {"192.168.1.40",(char *) 0};
```

to:

```
char *argV[] = {"/home/user/application", "192.168.1.40",(char *) 0};
```

The behaviour of the argv array is mentioned more explicitly later on:

> When a program is executed as a result of a posix_spawn() or posix_spawnp() call, it is entered as follows:

```
main(argc, argv, envp)
int argc;
char **argv, **envp;
```

> where argc is the number of elements in argv (the ''arg count'') and argv points to the array of character pointers to the arguments themselves.

Comment: Thanks, its working :) one more question... What about the executable path given in the argument of posix_spawn

Comment: That's the actual program that's launched. You use the first argument to argv to give it a name. Some programs change the name to match behaviour e.g. login shells displayed with a simple `ps` start with `-shell`, while the program name would be just `shell`