# C++ program is not exiting after starting new executable file

Tags: c++, system, c++98

Consider two C++ projects:

Project 1:

```
// projectOne.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Sleep(5000);
    system("projectTwo.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

Project 2:

```
// projectTwo.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Sleep(5000);
    system("projectOne.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

The behavior I seek is: `projectOne` starts => start `projectTwo` => `projectOne` ends => `projectTwo` will start projectOne => `projectTwo` ends => `projectOne` will start `projectTwo`.

However, the programs are not ending. For example, when `projectOne` starts `projectTwo`, it will not end `projectOne` when `return 0;` is run within `projectOne`. So after a few minutes, there will be multiple versions of the programs running at the same time. I was thinking it had to do with the `system` command. Maybe it waits until the project is complete until it goes to the next line of code, and this results in circling, but I am not sure. How can I fix this? I need the programs to end after one of them is called using the `system` command. I hope this question is clear.

Comment: `projectOne` starts `projectTwo` which starts `projectOne` which starts `projectTwo`, and so one ... So yes, this is endless.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

Comment: _"Maybe it waits until the project is complete until it goes to the next line of code, and this results in circling"_ Yes `system()` waits until the subprocess completes.

Comment: Please remove the `bash`tag, this is windows specific.

Comment: @kebs it actually has nothing to do with bash nor Windows, but `C`... :D

Comment: @norisknofun yes, but I want them to end when return 0 is executed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How do I start another program which does not wait until the sub-process completes?

Comment: you mean you want the program not to block on the `system` function ? If yes, add `#include <thread>` and replace the `system(...)`call by `std::thread([](){system(...);}).detach();` but I guess your computer will get headache because this is [fork-bomb pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)

Comment: It will never reach the `return 0;` command because it will wait for it's child process to die, which won't happen because it will wait for it's new child to terminate and so on.... basically you go around telling processes to spawn a new copy of itself (program1 and program2 are the same thing) and then finish, but as it will finish only after it's child has - you've run into a problem here. None of your children are finishing and are blocked from finishing. Make a `MAX_DEPTH` constant and don't let them raise more processes than that, and you should  be good.

Comment: @norisknofun Yes. How does one accomplish this?

Comment: If you are using a c++11 compliant compiler, use my previous comment.

Comment: @norisknofun unfortunately, I am stuck with C++98

Comment: Christine, threads still work in older C++ ;) just follow his idea - raise a thread to launch the other program and terminate, but this has a different problem - when a process dies, all of it's threads and subprocesses die as well. So when you kill the first one, all of them will die too. But I could be wrong.

Comment: What sort of portability do you want? Before C++11 there is no standard thread, and if you must use platform-specific threading, you might as well use platform-specific process launchers. `CreateProcess` is one for Windows-based OSes and `fork` may serve your purposes on POSIX-based systems

Comment: @user4581301 I don't need portability (only for windows), and I don't know much about threading. Could you provide an example of how I could use CreateProcess here?

Comment: [Straight from the mouth of madness... er Microsoft.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx) Addendum: You do not want to do the `WaitForSingleObject` as per the example. That will leave you where you are right now. Just skip that line.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you very much. Your suggestion to remove WaitForSingleObject solved the issue. I will mark your answer as best if you write it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system` blocks the running thread until `system` returns and `system` will not return until the executed process has terminated.

There are many ways to solve this problem. The simplest and most likely to be portable is to [use a `std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) to run `system` in a thread that runs concurrent to the main processing thread.

```
std::thread procthread([processToRun] {system(processToRun.c_str());});
procthread.detach();
```

Short, sweet, and as portable as anything calling `system` can be. The first line creates a thread and executes a lambda function that runs `system` on the provided process name. The second line disconnects the thread from the `std::thread` object and allows the thread to run free. Otherwise if `procthread` goes out of scope the thread will be terminated and bad things will very likely happen.

If you can't do this because your development system does not support C++11 or better, you can use operating system-specific threading, but if you have to use system-specific thread creation calls, you might as well use system-specific *process* creation calls to directly create the new process.

In POSIX systems, [`posix_spawn` will likely be the go-to function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn). I don't have a machine at my disposal to test this on at the moment, so I'll just link to [Starting a process using posix_spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546756/starting-a-process-using-posix-spawn).

Under Windows, [use CreateProcess or your variant of choice.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) The following code is based on [Microsoft's Creating Processes documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx) and modified to be a little less Microsoft specific and not wait for the spawned process to complete before continuing execution.

```
char processToRun[] = "process to run"; //NOTE: Not a std::string!
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));

// Start the child process.
if (!CreateProcess(NULL, // No module name (use command line)
                   processToRun, // Command line DANGER! won't accept const char* 
                                 // cannot use std::string::c_str
                   NULL, // Process handle not inheritable
                   NULL, // Thread handle not inheritable
                   FALSE, // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                   0, // No creation flags
                   NULL, // Use parent's environment block
                   NULL, // Use parent's starting directory
                   &si, // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                   &pi)) // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
{
    std::cerr << "CreateProcess failed ("<<GetLastError()<<").\n";
    return false;
}

// do stuff
// Close process and thread handles.
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
return true;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your approach makes in an endless loop and it will **not** end!!

> You are spawning multiple instances of projectOne and projectTwo which in turn are creating more.. It's recursive -_-

**EDIT**

> System **WAITS**!

---

**SOLUTION**

```
int execl(char * pathname, char * arg0, arg1, ..., argn, NULL);
```

Comment: @ChristineSimmons _"why are the old processes not ending?"_ As mentioned `system()` waits.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, this answer doesn't mention that at all.

Comment: @RobKennedy I mentioned it in a comment on the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks - Is there another function like system which does not wait?

Comment: @ChristineSimmons Lookup `fork()` and `exec()`.

Comment: @atefth but your answer does not provide a solution, but rather states why the issue persists which was already addressed by someone else

Comment: @ChristineSimmons haha it's cool man, anyway I think what you are looking for is execl;

Comment: @ChristineSimmons I've updated my answer, hope that will help you.

Comment: It was "not an answer" up until the edit; you might wanna refine it a bit.

Comment: @Shark tbh I thought this was a prank, cause obviously the OP was playing a joke making this recursive call.. I guess I was mistaken :|